# Tableau Scout 1.5 - how do we update log4j?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Scout is an exploratory testing tool that interacts with Tableau's Server or Desktop product in order to capture performance metrics for specific User actions across a set of workbooks.

Scout was updated to v1.5 on December 3rd, 2021, just before the log4j vulnerability. We have been unable to use Scout due to the vulnerability and are looking for options to get Scout running again.

Scout Getting Started page:
https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000G54CPSAZ/getting-started-scout

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to the latest Patch version of Tableau Server for any major version (which includes the logj4 update), they have resolved all vulnerabilities related to log4J.

Comment: Tableau Scout is a standalone install with it's own log4j

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Scout has been updated to 1.6, which includes fixing the log4j vulnerability.